# PANDAS efficient large dataframe iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm just starting with Python and because I'm an experienced R user I found that PANDAS would fit to the following situation. I tried to describe it clearly, so

The situation is:

> - Large dataframe (filled with 0s) with colnames and rownames (dimensions 85558 x 85558)
> - Tab-delimited file.

My question:

> - ¿how can efficiently iterate over each cell of the dataframe, and fill with counts if succesful comparisons are achieved between information contained in (colnames AND rownames) vs flags present at each line of the file parsed?

I already have a function which will compare rownames/colnames vs flags. So lets suppose that once  efficient access to each cell is achieved call the function (i.ex. **compare_and_count()**), parse colnames and rownames as arguments, and return a count or not. Logically, counts will be added to the dataframe cells, and if previous counts are present then will sum it.

Just as additional information here is a preview of the dataframe:

```
    chr6:0-2000 chr6:2000-4000  chr6:4000-6000  chr6:6000-8000  ... chr6:171114000-171115067
chr6:0-2000 0   0   0   0   ... 0
chr6:2000-4000  0   0   0   0   ... 0
chr6:4000-6000  0   0   0   0   ... 0
…   …   …   …   …   …
chr6:171110000-171112000    0   0   0   0   ... 0
chr6:171112000-171114000    0   0   0   0   ... 0
chr6:171114000-171115067    0   0   0   0   ... 0
```

I've tried to not reapeat already answered questions and I think this has the specifity that is a large dataframe which information about rownames and colnames have to be considered carefully.

I thank everybody who can add it's knowledge to the answer!

Best!

------------- **EDIT** --------------------

As additional explanation, because suggested by the comments here is my typical input and the desired output:

The input consist of a series of grouped coordinates delimited by lines. Each line has to be treated separately one from another:

```
Ids CHR-1   START-1 CHR-2   START-2
id1 chr6    1   chr6    100
id2 chr6    1995    chr6    2200
id3 chr6    2300    chr6    2500
id4 chr6    3300    chr6    3500
id5 chr6    3447    chr6    3658
id6 chr6    5000    chr6    5100
id7 chr6    5050    chr6    5150
id8 chr6    6000    chr6    6100
```

As you can see in the first Dataframe there are a bunch coordinates as rownames and colnames. The objective then, is to map the line-grouped coordinates from the file in the big dataframe. For example, the following coordinate:

```
id1 chr6    1   chr6    100
```

Should only be counted in **cell[1,1]** because the start-1 and start-2 are in between 0-2000. However, the next coordinate:

```
id2 chr6    1995    chr6    2200
```

Should only be counted in **cell[1,2]** because the start-1 is between 0-2000 **BUT** start-2 is in between 2000-4000.

The final output will be the matrix with the grouped coordinates mapped in the dataframe:

```
    chr6:0-2000 chr6:2000-4000  chr6:4000-6000  chr6:6000-8000  ... chr6:171114000-171115067
chr6:0-2000 1   2   0   0   ... 0
chr6:2000-4000  0   1   0   0   ... 0
chr6:4000-6000  0   0   1   0   ... 0
…   …   …   …   …   …
chr6:171110000-171112000    0   0   0   0   ... 0
chr6:171112000-171114000    0   0   0   0   ... 0
chr6:171114000-171115067    0   0   0   0   ... 0
```

As you can denote, for this example I do not take into consideration if there are different IDs in the same line, which therefore is something can be solved with a combination of if/else statements with a slightly different Dataframe. My principal worry is to **iterate & count using the minimum possible time**.

Does this clarify the situation?
Thanks!

Comment: could you add simple example of your input (DataFrame + file) and desired output? Something small, like 5x6 DataFrame, just to get an idea of what you trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to why you have the `CHR-1` and `CHR-2` columns, they don't seem to add anything. Here's my example `DataFrame`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[500, 200], [600,1100], [500, 2200]], columns=['a','b'])

>>> df
     a     b
0  500   200
1  600  1100
2  500  2200
```

You want to bin elements by multiples of 2000 so:

```
df /= 2000
>>> df
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  0  1
```

Now we can see that `cell[0,0]` should have 2 counts and `cell[0,1]` should have 1 count. We accomplish this with the `groupby` method and use `count` as our aggregator:

```
c = df.groupby(['a','b']).size()
>>> c
a  b
0  0    2
   1    1
```

Now we can get the counts of a cell with:

```
>>> c.loc[0,0]
2
>>> c.loc[0,1]
1
```